# Twig replace regex

Tags: templating, replace, regex

As I understand, craft overrides Twig's `replace` filter to allow for the use of regex; which is just running `preg_replace` under the hood

When running the following regex through `preg_replace` in a php page (outside of craft) in order to match non-ASCII characters; it works as expected:

```
/([^ !"#$%&\'\(\)*\+,-\.\/0123456789:;<=>\?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\[\]\^\\\_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{\|}~\n]+)/u
```

However, when running it through `replace` in a template in craft; nothing is matched

Any ideas as to why this is happening and possible solutions?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doubling-up your backslashes:

https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/filters#replace

Comment: Good shout, that fixed it. Any idea why double back-slashes are required?

Comment: I don't know exactly for sure, but in general whenever you're passing one language through to another (in this case, passing a regex through twig), you need to double-escape if both languages share the same escape characters. Because the first language (twig in this case) will escape the backslash, but you want an actual backslash passed through to the regex (so it can then escape the character after it), so you need to tell twig "I want an actual backslash here to be sent to the regex". Or something like that.